# Can't read any created Junctions

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

I'm using Windows 10 tech preview.

Anytime I create a junction (using either mklink from cmd or junction.exe here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx ), I cannot load it with Windows Explorer, nor does it work with any applications. I used this same technique in Windows 7 and Windows 8 with never an issue.

I get this error:

**You don't currently have permission to access this folder.
Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder.**

Clicking Continue yields this error:

**You have been denied permission to access this folder. 
To gain access to this folder, you will need to use the security tab.**

I am the only user, and an administrator. The security tab does not shed light -- *SYSTEM, Administrators, and my user account* all have full allow permissions on this folder. I have created multiple junctions and none seem to work.

Comment: This started happening for me as well after the last update. It could be a bug.

Comment: Given that Microsoft has added support for Symbolic Links to the New-Item, Remove-Item and Get-ChildItem cmdlets in PowerShell 5 (and that they could also be adding support for Junction Links), this behavior maybe a side effect of the work in that area.

Comment: In light of this I will close the question and see if I can dig up any development info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the issue was not solved with the build 9860. It's just a bit less annoying (it take less time for Windows to free the symlink/junction).

If you want more informations, there is a thread on Technet. I explain which tests I did.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4c69272-0329-496e-8c83-05a15d9b284b/problems-with-symbolic-links-whines-about-missing-permissions?forum=WinPreview2014Feedback

Edit 11/14 :
Issue seems to be solved with the installation of the new build 9879.

Answer (score 3):

This bug was fixed in the newest Build 9860

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; can confirm, it's fixed for me too